# Wordpress post meta array issues with custom plugins

Tags: wordpress

I have a website in my local xamp and online with shared hosting with wordpress.
I have a custom plugins through which admin can upload multiples files into a particular user account. In test server its allowing only 139 Files not more and throwing "User ID Not Found" warning, for that a admin cannot upload more than 140 files.

But in Xampp its working fine with all over 140 files.

I have tried with so many online servers but there is no luck.

I have given test server ids for more checking.

http://www.webapplications.co.in/rcmfire/wp-admin/ (Admin can only upload files to users) UID : adm Pass: admin@123

Admin is trying to upload a file through http://www.webapplications.co.in/rcmfire/wp-admin/users.php

(Try for the user UID : smasotto and password :go4ers#1 ) user id no 20 on second page, User Name : 1smas smasotto

In this page you will see for 139 number file you cannot update and its showing In Invalid user ID.

Which same thing is in showing at by hitting this http://www.webapplications.co.in/rcmfire/wp-admin/user-edit.php

The Plugin - http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=10076114594307435772

The Screenshot: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=40576429452374775368

Thanks!

Comment: Is this working fine in local host? Its not a php error may be memeory issues in your shared server.

Comment: Yes its working fine and in other hsoting we have good memory too.

Comment: It is something issues related to our HTTP_REFERER in your plugin. its directly redirecting to user-edit.php without any query string. Its may be server issues with memory or post size.